# Prove $\sqrt[3]{4} - \sqrt[3]{3} < \sqrt[3]{3} - \sqrt[3]{2}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, number-comparison

I am a student in Germany, and I prepare for Math Olympiad by solving math problems. I have been solving the following question, which took about 4 hours to solve.

Prove the following inequality without using calculator:
$$\sqrt[3]{4} - \sqrt[3]{3} < \sqrt[3]{3} - \sqrt[3]{2}$$

Can you check my proof? It would be really grateful.

First, we can define function $f(x)$ as following:
$$f(x) = \sqrt[3]{x+1} - \sqrt[3]{x}\space(x > 0)$$
$$f(3) = \sqrt[3]{3+1} - \sqrt[3]{3} = \sqrt[3]{4} - \sqrt[3]{3}$$
$$f(2) = \sqrt[3]{2+1} - \sqrt[3]{2} = \sqrt[3]{3} - \sqrt[3]{2}$$

Then, we will differentiate $f(x)$ to check whether $f(x)$ is a decreasing function or not. $f '(x)$ must be a falling function if $f '(x)$ < 0.
$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2}} - \frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{x^2}}$$
Since the minuend is smaller than the subtrahend (minuend has a bigger denominator than the denominator of subtrahend), we can say $f '(x)$ is less than 0 which makes $f(x)$ a decreasing function. Falling function means that $f(a) > f(a+1)$. Substitute $a=2$ and we get:
$$f(2) > f(3)$$
$$\sqrt[3]{3} - \sqrt[3]{2} > \sqrt[3]{4} - \sqrt[3]{3}$$
$$\sqrt[3]{4} - \sqrt[3]{3} < \sqrt[3]{3} - \sqrt[3]{2}$$

Thank you for reading this text, but it would be more grateful if you check my solution, and  comment my solution.

I wish you a beautiful day, and stay safe.

Comment: Of course, there would be a better way, but somehow this way of proof was much easier for me.

Comment: Your proof is fine.

Comment: @lhf Thank you very very much for your comment!

Comment: Amazing proof!!! Loved it.

Comment: @Math_Buddy Thank you very much for your kind comment!

Comment: Nice done. Note that essentially what you are using is that, called $g(x)=x^{1/3}$, $g'(x)$ is a decreasing function, that is $g(x)$ is concave. In fact, if you draw the graph of $x^{1/3}$, it is clear from the drawing that the "vertical" distance between $g(4)$ and $g(3)$ is less than that between $g(3)$ and $g(2)$ just from the fact that it is concave.

Comment: nice proof  but always remember  **It’s also good to remember that professional mathematics is not a sport (in sharp contrast to mathematics competitions). The objective in mathematics is not to obtain the highest ranking, the highest “score”, or the highest number of prizes and awards; instead, it is to increase understanding of mathematics (both for yourself, and for your colleagues and students), and to contribute to its development and applications. For these tasks, mathematics needs all the good people it can get.- Terence Tao**

Comment: @프로형 "f′(x)  must be a falling function if f′(x) < 0*" You meant "***f(x)*** *must be a decreasing function...*".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is fine. If you want a non-calculus approach, note that
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= (x+1)^{1/3}-x^{1/3} 
\\
&= \dfrac{\left((x+1)^{1/3}-x^{1/3}\right)\left((x+1)^{2/3}+(x+1)^{1/3}x^{1/3}+x^{2/3}\right)}{(x+1)^{2/3}+2(x+1)^{1/3}x^{1/3}+x^{2/3}}
\\
&= \dfrac{(x+1)-x}{(x+1)^{2/3}+(x+1)^{1/3}x^{1/3}+x^{2/3}}
\\
&= \dfrac{1}{(x+1)^{2/3}+(x+1)^{1/3}x^{1/3}+x^{2/3}}
\end{align*}
is clearly decreasing since the numerator is constant and positive while the denominator is increasing and positive. Hence, $f(3) < f(2)$.

Comment: Amazing solution without calculus! It is clear to say this way of solving is very interesting!

Answer (score 1):

I guess your question has been answered. Here is a different way to see it. Note that one has $$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2).$$ It follows that $$1=(\sqrt[3]{4}-\sqrt[3]{3})(\sqrt[3]{16}+\sqrt[3]{12}+\sqrt[3]{9})=(\sqrt[3]{3}-\sqrt[3]{2})(\sqrt[3]{9}+\sqrt[3]{6}+\sqrt[3]{4}).$$ It suffices now to show that $$\sqrt[3]{16}+\sqrt[3]{12}+\sqrt[3]{9}>\sqrt[3]{9}+\sqrt[3]{6}+\sqrt[3]{4}$$

$$\Leftrightarrow \sqrt[3]{16}+\sqrt[3]{12}>\sqrt[3]{6}+\sqrt[3]{4},$$ which is clear.

Comment: Logical and simple as well!

Answer (score 1):

The standard difference quotient for approximating $f''(a)$ is
$$ \frac{f(a-h) - 2 f(a) + f(a+h)}{h^2}  $$
Here $f(x) = \sqrt[3]x $  is infinitely differentiable, while the **second and fourth derivatives are negative** for $0 < h < a.$ Indeed
$$ f(a-h) - 2 f(a) + f(a+h)  = f''(a) h^2 + \frac{h^3}{6} \left( f'''( \xi) - f'''(\eta)  \right)  $$

where $ a-h < \eta < a < \xi < a+h .$  This is just the Taylor series with remainder. As the fourth derivative is negative  we see $ f'''( \xi) - f'''(\eta) < 0.$  Thus we find,
$$ f(a-h) - 2 f(a) + f(a+h) <0$$

Her $f$ is the cube root, $a=3$ and $h=1$ so
$$  \sqrt[3]2  - 2\sqrt[3]3 +  \sqrt[3]4 < 0  $$

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is right.

I think, there is something better.

We can use the following identity.
$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=\frac{1}{2}(a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2.$$
We obtain:
$$  \sqrt[3]2  - 2\sqrt[3]3 +  \sqrt[3]4 < 0  $$ it's
$$2-24+4+3\cdot\sqrt[3]2\cdot2\sqrt[3]3\cdot\sqrt[3]4 < 0 $$ or
$$12\sqrt[3]3<18$$ or
$$24<27,$$ which is true.

Id est, $$\sqrt[3]2  - 2\sqrt[3]3 +  \sqrt[3]4 < 0$$ is true.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach

No calculators allowed. 
**Requires** knowledge that 
$\log_{10} (2) \approx 0.301$ and $\log_{10} (3) \approx 0.477.$

The problem reduces to showing that
$(4)^{(1/3)} + (2)^{(1/3)} < 2(3)^{(1/3)}.$

Cubing both sides, this resolves to showing that 
$4 + 2 + 3\left[4^{(2/3)}2^{(1/3)} + 4^{(1/3)}2^{(2/3)}\right] < 24.$

This in turn resolves to showing that 
$4^{(2/3)}2^{(1/3)} + 4^{(1/3)}2^{(2/3)} < 6.$

Converting to logarithms, base $(10)$, 
this resolves to showing that 
$10^{(1.505/3)} + 10^{(1.204/3)} < 6.$

This resolves to showing that

$$10^{(0.5017)} + 10^{(0.4014)} < 6.\tag 1$$

$\log_{10}(3.2) \approx (5 \times 0.301) - 1 = 0.505.$ 
Therefore, $10^{(0.5017)} < 3.2.$

Further, $\log_{10} (2.7) \approx (0.477 \times 3) - 1 = 0.431.$ 
Therefore $10^{(0.4014)} < 2.7.$

Therefore, the LHS of expression (1) above is $< 5.9$.

Comment: Yes! This way of approach is amazing as well!

Answer (score 0):

Consider also a simpler function $g(x) = \sqrt[3]x$. For $x > 0$, $g'(x) = \dfrac1{3x^{2/3}}$ is decreasing.

By mean value theorem, there exists some $c_1 \in (2,3)$ and some $c_2 \in (3,4)$ that satisfy

$$g'(c_1) = \frac{\sqrt[3]3-\sqrt[3]2}{1};\quad g'(c_2) = \frac{\sqrt[3]4-\sqrt[3]3}{1}$$

And since $c_2 > c_1$ and so $g'(c_2) < g'(c_1)$,

$$\sqrt[3]4-\sqrt[3]3 < \sqrt[3]3-\sqrt[3]2$$

Comment: True and more simple! Math is just about simplicity, and this kind of approach is what is math for!